# Unable to click on signs on a map

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in Python in association with selenium to click on each of the signs available in a map. However, when I execute my script, it throws `timeout exception` error upon reaching this line `wait.until(EC.staleness_of(item))`.

Before hitting that line, the script should have clicked once but It could not? How can I click on all the signs in that map cyclically?

[This is the site link](https://www.findapetwash.com/).

This is my code so far ***(perhaps, I'm trying with the wrong selectors):***

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = "https://www.findapetwash.com/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#map .gm-style"))):
    item.click()
    wait.until(EC.staleness_of(item))
driver.quit()
```

Signs visible on that map like:

[image]

> Post script: I know that this is their API `https://www.findapetwash.com/api/locations/getAll/` using which I can get the JSON content but I would like to stick to the Selenium way. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can, those signs are not part of the html. As a work around you could open the list in the right side and click the items from there, but if this is not just for practice I think the API is your best solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can click one by one using Selenium if, for some reasons, you cannot use API. Also it is possible to extract information for each sign without clicking on them with Selenium.

Here code to click one by one:

```
signs = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.marker.marker--list")))
for sign in signs:
     driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", sign)
     #do something
```

Try also without wait, probably will work.

Answer (score 5):

I know you wrote you don't want to use the API but using Selenium to get the locations from the map markers seems a bit overkill for this, instead, why not making a call to their Web service using requests and parse the returned json?

Here is a working script:

```
import requests
import json

api_url='https://www.findapetwash.com/api/locations/getAll/'

class Location:
    def __init__(self, json):
        self.id=json['id']
        self.user_id=json['user_id']
        self.name=json['name']
        self.address=json['address']
        self.zipcode=json['zipcode']
        self.lat=json['lat']
        self.lng=json['lng']
        self.price_range=json['price_range']
        self.photo='https://www.findapetwash.com' + json['photo']

def get_locations():
    locations = []
    response = requests.get(api_url)
    if response.ok:
        result_json = json.loads(response.text)
        for location_json in result_json['locations']:
            locations.append(Location(location_json))

        return locations
    else:
        print('Error loading locations')
        return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    locations = get_locations()
    for l in locations:
        print(l.name)
```

**Selenium**

If you still want to go the Selenium way, instead of waiting until all the elements are loaded, you could just halt the script for some seconds or even a minute to make sure everything is loaded, this should fix the timeout exception:

```
import time 

driver.get(link)
# Wait 20 seconds
time.sleep(20)
```

For other possible workarounds, see the accepted answer here: [Make Selenium wait 10 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45347675/make-selenium-wait-10-seconds)

Comment: The OP explicitly stated they would rather not use the API and stick with Selenium
Edit: got addressed now it seems

Comment: I know, but the code hurt my eyes so I wrote a more bulletproof solution. I have added a remark though, thanks.

Comment: Using the API definitely is the more elegant way, agreed